# react-native run-ios results to error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-<<ProjectName>>...'

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I'm receiving following **error** while trying to run my old `react-native` project.

```
❌  error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-<<ProjectName>>/Pods-<<ProjectName>>-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target '<<ProjectName>>' from project '<<ProjectName>>')
```

Also tried to go into an iOS directory and run pod install. In this case I'm receiving invalid podfile.

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 
[!] Invalid `RNReanimated.podspec` file: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class.
```

[image]